# "Catedral da sé" é uma redundância (ou pleonasmo)?

Tags: redundâncias, pleonasmo

A definição de catedral diz que "sé" é um dos seus sinônimos:
https://www.dicio.com.br/catedral/

- *Igreja principal de um bispado ou arcebispado, onde a autoridade eclesiástica tem sede; sé; matriz.*

Ainda assim é correto dizer "catedral da sé"? Ou sé aqui deveria estar com inicial maiúscula (Sé) referindo-se a um nome de lugar? Aliás todas iniciais maiúsculas é forma normal observada quando se referem à catedral no centro de São Paulo: *Catedral da Sé*.

Uma pesquisa por "catedral da sé" (digitar isso entre aspas no Google) retorna inúmeros resultados, mas seguem alguns exemplos:

- https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catedral_Metropolitana_de_S%C3%A3o_Paulo
- https://www.anoregsp.org.br/noticias/71196/strongcatedral-da-se-do-centro-de-sao-paulo-para-o-mundostrong
- https://catracalivre.com.br/agenda/concertos-da-cripta-da-catedral-da-se/
- https://spcity.com.br/conheca-a-cripta-da-catedral-da-se/

Comment: Jurisdição episcopal.

"sé", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/s%C3%A9 [consultado em 02-03-2022].

Comment: Diz-se *cartedral da sé* para os teus lados? Eu nunca ouvi. Mas por aqui ouve-se *sé catedral*, que dá um bocado no mesmo...

Comment: @Jacinto: adicionei referências

Comment: "Sé" (o bairro onde fica localizado a catedral, marco zero da cidade de São Paulo). Quem mora em São Paulo refere ao local desta forma, assim como a Praça da Sé, Estação do Metrô Sé. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9_(distrito_de_S%C3%A3o_Paulo)

Answer (score 1):

> (...) é correto dizer **"catedral da sé"**?
>
> Ou sé aqui deveria estar com inicial maiúscula (Sé) referindo-se a um nome de lugar?

A palavra **sé** pode escrever-se com minúscula **sé** ou maiúscula **Sé** dependendo se referir-se a:

1. Um toponímio

   E.g. A antiga [freguesia da **Sé de Lisboa**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9_(Lisboa)), hoje mudou o nome da freguesia mas essa zona central da cidade continua a chamar-se *"a Sé"*.

   Ver também

   > Formulário Ortográfico de 1943
   >
   > [XVI - EMPREGO DAS INICIAIS MAIÚSCULAS - 49](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php%3Faction%3Dacordo%26id%3D16-49%26version%3D1943)
   >
   > 2º Nos substantivos próprios de qualquer espécie ... (**topônimos**)
2. Um organismo pontífico

   > [Código do direito canónico](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/portuguese/codex-iuris-canonici_po.pdf)
   >
   > **Cân. 361** — Com o nome de **Sé Apostólica** ou **Santa Sé** designam-se neste Código não só o Romano Pontífice, mas ainda, a não ser que por natureza das coisas ou do contexto outra coisa se deduza, a Secretaria de Estado, o Conselho para os negócios públicos da Igreja, e os demais Organismos da Cúria Romana

   > Formulário Ortográfico de 1943
   >
   > [XVI - EMPREGO DAS INICIAIS MAIÚSCULAS - 49](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php%3Faction%3Dacordo%26id%3D16-49%26version%3D1943)
   >
   > 5º - Nos nomes que designam altos conceitos religiosos
3. O assento episcopal de uma diocese

   > [Código do direito canónico](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/portuguese/codex-iuris-canonici_po.pdf)
   >
   > **Cân. 409** — § 1. Vagando **a sé episcopal**, o Bispo coadjutor torna-se imediatamente Bispo da diocese para a qual fora constituído
4. Por fim dizer *Sé Catedral* (ou Catedral da Sé) refere-se a um edifício e é o nome composto abreviado de *catedral da sé da diocese (ou do arciprestado)*.

   > Formulário Ortográfico de 1943
   >
   > [XVI - EMPREGO DAS INICIAIS MAIÚSCULAS - 49](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php%3Faction%3Dacordo%26id%3D16-49%26version%3D1943)
   >
   > 8º - Nos nomes de (...) edifícios e estabe­lecimentos públicos ou particulares:

Answer (score 1):

A expressão "Catedral da Sé/sé", pelo menos aos ouvidos de alguns, é historicamente um pouco circular, mas faz sentido. Citando da [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9_episcopal):

- De fato, "sé" (que vem de "sede", latim *sedes*) originalmente é a catedral:

  > refere-se a uma catedral, lugar onde um bispo tem sua cátedra, o lugar a partir de onde o bispo exerce sua jurisdição
- Contudo:

  > Por extensão acaba referindo-se também ao território onde um bispo [...] exerce seu governo eclesiástico

Ou seja, por vezes acontece de a região ou bairro contendo a catedral passar a ser conhecido ou mesmo denominado oficialmente como "Sé" — e, assim, ao menos informalmente, muitos se referem à "catedral da Sé" com o significado de "catedral que fica na Sé", ao menos em pt-BR.

Dois exemplos importantes de topônimos derivados são a [Sé (bairro de São Paulo)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9_(distrito_de_S%C3%A3o_Paulo)) e a [Sé (antiga freguesia de Lisboa)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9_(Lisboa)), que abrigam, respectivamente, a [Catedral da Sé](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catedral_Metropolitana_de_S%C3%A3o_Paulo) e a [Sé de Lisboa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9_de_Lisboa), mas várias outras cidades têm suas Sés.

Comment: Tens a certeza que "catedral da sé" é "catedral da região/bairro da sé"? O Fernão Lopes no século XV usava aparentemente como equivalentes "igreja catedral", "igreja catedral da sé", "sé" e "sé catedral". Arriscas-te a estar a propor uma explicação para um termo pelos menos 600 anos depois de ele ter entrado em uso.

Comment: @Jacinto Só tenho certeza de que é assim que eu pessoalmente (e os lusófonos próximos que consultei) sempre entendi. Em pt-BR jamais ouvi "sé catedral" ou "igreja catedral". Editei a resposta para deixar claro que as pessoas podem usar o termo com esse significado, não que esse seja o significado oficial ou histórico.

Comment: Acho engraçado que quem usa/entende com esse significado, essencialmente está dizendo "a igreja do bairro da igreja" quando diz "catedral da Sé". :-)

Comment: Era isso que eu ia dizer. Ou melhor, "catedral do bairro da catedral" (nem todas as igrejas são sés; só as catedrais) ou ainda "sé do bairro da sé". Catedral originalmente era só adjetivo, não podias dizer só "catedral" ou "catedral da sé".

Comment: Estou a pensar, que na tua interpretação "catedral da sé" é uma designação local -- a catedral deste bairro que se chama sé -- como "sé nova de Coimbra" por exemplo, com a diferença de haver vária catedrais com esse nome; como em Portugal encontras um "café da vila" em muitas vilas. Mas eu encontrei na net brasileiros a chamar "catedral da sé" à sé do Porto e à de Lisboa, que não são conhecidas localmente por "catedral da sé". Parece-me portanto que para alguns brasileiros "catedral da sé" é uma designação genérica para "catedral"?

Comment: @Jacinto Interessante. É possível mesmo, talvez também tenha a ver com a familiaridade do falante com as instituições da igreja católica (que conheçam as definições de sé, catedral, etc.). Mas acho mais provável ser mais por associação ­— acostumados com a expressão "catedral da sé" e ouvindo o lugar ser chamado de "sé", usam a expressão que já conhecem.